# How can I remove the white background of cursor bubble from EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

How can I remove that white background of the bubble from the `EditText`

[image]

Following is the Applications theme from **Style.xml** from version 21

```
 <style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/DefaultTextAppearance</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/dividerDark</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimaryLight</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorPrimaryLight</item>
    <item name="actionModeStyle">@style/ActionMode</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeStyle">@style/ActionMode</item>
    <item name="android:splitMotionEvents">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowEnableSplitTouch">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Is that the default bubble? If not, post your custom xml code here

Comment: Yes, It is default bubble.

Comment: Can you post your `styles.xml` code here?

Comment: @dustblue check, I post application theme above

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. It was due to **android:popupBackground**, After removing this it's working fine.